# "bring in a lot more new business"

Tags: phrase-meaning

This is from [the Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary.](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/bring-in?q=Bring%20in)

> We need to **bring in a lot more new business**.

Which of the following two does the phrase in bold mean?

1. introduce a lot more new activities of making, buying, selling or supplying goods or services for money
2. attract and acquire a lot more new customers or clients

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a native US English speaker, I would only ever interpret it to mean #2, "attract and acquire new customers."

You can see it used this way in this article, ["6 steps I followed to get hundreds of new clients — without spending a dime on advertising or marketing"](https://www.businessinsider.com/ways-to-get-new-clients-without-paying-for-marketing-advertising-2020-10)

> 6. **Create superfan customers** 
>    I prioritized over-delivering for my customers to ensure they were happy with my service. This helped me create superfan customers who would share my information with their friends and networks, and also be happy to act as a good referral. Sometimes I'd ask past customers to share my information, or I'd offer them a free service (like a check-up phone call) if they brought in a new customer.
>    Think about how you can encourage past customers who enjoyed your product or working with you to become ambassadors who help **bring in new business**.

You can see how the phrase is associated with *referrals*, and *new customers*.

Interpretation #1, "introduce a lot more new activities" doesn't really fit because [*business* means something like "dealings or transactions, especially of an economic nature"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/business); because *business* here is a mass noun, which doesn't suggest "multiple new activities", but a unified thing; and because the phrase *bring in* implies something coming from the outside to us, not just us doing something new.

Comment: I understand. Thank you very much.

Comment: If you bring in more customers, you might also need more business activities (making, buying, selling, etc) but customers or sales is definitely the primary meaning.

Comment: @StuartF Thank you very much.